# What is Rinman's green used for?

Tags: metallurgy

I can't find any info about it's uses neither in book nor in internet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well my friend Google says it is Cobalt green. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_green

Comment: And it also says 
"It is rarely used because it is a weak chromophore and relatively expensive compared to chromium(III) oxide"
So, aren't they used at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to it being a weak chromophore and relatively expensive than chromium(III) oxide, its use as a pigment has become obsolete. Since it is kind of malleable and it is resistant to oxidation, it is hence used for sheeting, coating galvanized iron, etc. It is used in making brass and other alloys, and is also largely consumed in electric batteries. Also, it magnetic at room temperature, so it is used in [spintropic devices](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spintronics).

**References**

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt_green)
2. [Findwords](https://findwords.info/term/rinmann's%20green)

Answer (score 2):

I can't really imagine that it's used as pigment. First of all it contains cobalt in comparison to the less harmful Cr(III). Another thing that bothers me about the compound is its composition. While Thenard's Blue is what we call a spinel-structure, Rinman's Green isn't one. Although textbooks sometimes tell you this and quite often students try to convince me it's just not the case. At this point I will then ask my students for the color and one simple concept that I often use is that we start from ZnO in a wurzite structure. In there some zinc ions are replaced by cobalt. This gives us cobalt in a $\ce{[CoO4]^6-}$ tetrahedral environment. While octahedrally coordinated cobalt(II) is often pink, tetrahedrally coordinated cobalt(II) is usually blue. We see this in the example of Thenard's Blue $\ce{Co[Al2O4]}$. So we expect the cobalt part in Rinnman's green to introduce a blue color but what we get is green.

And the easiest way to explain that is that $\ce{ZnO}$ tends to become yellow at elevated temperatures. Usually this is reversible but let's just say a yellow color introduced by high-temperatures solid state phases containing $\ce{ZnO}$ is at least plausible. Then those two components will mix to form the color green.

When we do this as test for zinc in the lab I get a lot of different colors from blue to green. If you heat it too much or too long or you use too much cobalt you will even end up with black. And the cobalt(II) composition in the literature varies quite much.

So I can imagine, and that's really just my idea here, that it might be hard to reproduce the exact same green colors every time which makes it not very suitable for a commercial product. But I could as well just be mistaking here and there's an industrial way. If we make it with students however you will always find impurities or not fully mixed phases.

Answer (score 1):

The main use of Rinmann's green is analytical. It may be used to identify small amounts of zinc in a mixture. If a precipitate containing metal hydroxides and sulfides is burnt and calcined on a porcelain lid in a Bunsen flame, one may usually obtain a white or grayish mass. If now one drop of a diluted solution of $Co(NO_3)_2$ is added to the mass, and then calcined again, a green and non fusible mass is obtained if there is $Zn$ in the mass. This reaction is characteristic for zinc $Zn$. It is easy to do in the lab.

Comment: A test for Zn would be a qualitative analysis, not an analytical analysis.